# How to update image source based on Ember.select selection?

Tags: ember.js

I have a array of objects like this:

```
App.actors = [
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "John", id: 1, photo: 'img/john.png'}),
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Deneris", id: 2, photo: 'img/deneris.png'})
   ];
```

And display a select field like this:

```
 {{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="App.actors "
       valueBinding="someotherplace"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.firstName" id="selectedActor"}}
```

And now i would like to display a image with a selected photo of a actor after person changes selection. I tried like this:

```
<img  {{bindAttr src="App.actors.photo"}}>
```

But it does not work. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `App.actors` is an array, whereas you are giving App.actors.photo as `bindAttr`'s path, which is undefined.
All you need to do is give selectionBinding to your select, and take the photo from the selection.

```
{{view Ember.Select  
   contentBinding="App.actors "  
   valueBinding="someotherplace"  
   optionValuePath="content.id"  
   optionLabelPath="content.firstName"  
   selectionBinding="someOtherSelection"  
}}
```

And `<img  {{bindAttr src="someOtherSelection.photo"}}>`